# Best way to get MD5 of stream and then pass stream to a reader in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, amazon-s3

I'm parsing an email and whenever I hit an attachment, I want to upload the attachment to S3. Whenever an attachment is found I get a stream for the attachment. I want to get the MD5sum of the attachment, then upload it to S3 using the stream again.

Is there anyway to do this without first writing the stream to a file, calculating MD5, then making a readable stream from the file and sending a stream to knox (which would be 3 stream reads)?

```
parser.on("attachment", function(attachment){
    //Calculate MD5 sum
    var md5sum = '';
    s3client.putStream(attachment.stream, 'blah.jpeg', {
        'md5sum': md5sum
    }, function(err, res) {});
});
```

Comment: Any reason to not calculate the md5 as it's being uploaded to S3?

Comment: Once it's uploaded you can move the object using 'x-amz-copy-source' and assign it the md5.

Comment: S3 returns an error if it finds that the MD5 you provided doesn't match the MD5 it computed. @RyanOlds, Would copy source return an error if the md5 doesn't match?

Comment: I don't know, I have limited knowledge of S3. If the md5 is required  , then you will either have to stream it in to an array of buffers (memory hungry) or write it to disk (slower, but not memory hungry). The md5 can be computed while doing either of these. You know what to do after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work?

```
var crypt = require("crypto")

function hashFile(attachment){
    var hash = crypt.createHash("md5")
        .update(attachment)
        .digest("base64");


    console.log(hash);
}

hashFile("some attachment blah");
```

Where the attachment you pass in get's MD5 hashed and return base64 encoded (you could also specify binary, or hex in the digest method)

**UPDATE** Ok so I looked at that mail parser and notice what it says in the help:

https://github.com/andris9/mailparser#default-behavior

Notice the mention of the checksum property.

Now look at line 283 here: https://github.com/andris9/mailparser/blob/master/lib/mailparser.js

That checksum is the MD5 you want.

**So just do attachment.checksum and be done**

Comment: Wouldn't this use up the stream? So, I wouldn't be able to send the stream again to S3

Comment: I think I am missing something. The parser.on method... where is that coming from? i.e. How are you parsing the email. The attachment you are passing, is that not the complete attachment file?

Comment: It's npm's mailparser. It returns a stream to the attachment

Comment: wow totally didn't even think that mailparser would do that. Thanks a lot! It's still interesting though how this would be done if you only had a stream and wanted to get the md5 of it while also sending it to S3